# Records Won't be Added to Access Database WPF c#

Tags: c#, database, wpf, ms-access

I am working on a project, and i want to insert new row each time i click a button in my access database.

The problem is that everytime i click the button i can see the records added in my GridView, but when i close the program the data is lost, and they are not saved to the database.

Can anyone tell me why?

My code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    OleDbConnection con;
    DataTable dt;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=.\\PhysioDatabase.accdb"; //" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Clients";
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ClientDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();



    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        cmd.Connection = con;



                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Clients(CName,CSurname) Values('" + 3 + "','" +3  + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                BindGrid();


                MessageBox.Show("Added");

            }

        }
```

Comment: what is your CName and CSurname column type? Int or string?

Comment: Is that your actual code? Not maybe starting a transaction that is not committed in your actual code? This code here looks fine. Have you checked whether there is maybe a build step that deletes or replaces the accdb file?

Comment: @MrHery It is a String. Does it matter?

Comment: @NineBerry This is the whole code. I made a simple project to explain to problem , because the other project was huge. What could overwrite the accdb file?